# Spring actuator's liveness and readiness are returning 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator

So this is my configuration in application.yaml:

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: "ALWAYS"
      probes:
        enabled: true
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: true
    web:
      exposure:
        include: metrics, health, caches, restart
```

And according to documentations this should be enough for enabling liveness and readiness probe for a spring application. But the endpoints (`/actuator/health/liveness` and `/actuator/health/readiness`) are still returning 404. I tried many combinations in the config, but nothing works. Can you please tell me what to do about this?

Comment: Hey, did you mange to solve it? need any help?

Answer (score 9):

I dug a bit deeper in this issue as I found it as an interesting feature of `spring-boot-actuator`.
From my research I found out that this feature with `liveness` and `readiness` has been introduced in `spring-boot:2.3.0` so if you're using an older version this might be the reason you're not receiving the expected result when you do a `GET /actuator/health/readiness`.

If you upgrade your `spring-boot` version to >= **2.3.0** you can enable the liveness and readiness probes by adding:

```
management:
  health:
    probes:
      enabled: true
```

to your **application.yaml** file.
After doing so you should be able to

`GET /actuator/health`

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "groups": [
        "liveness",
        "readiness"
    ]
}
```

However for spring-boot versions >= 2.3.2 it is advised to enable probes by using the following in your application.yaml

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      probes:
        enabled: true
```

The reason for doing so is a bug which you can read more about [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22107)

**Extra tip**: If you're `spring-boot` version >= 2.3.0, you've configured your application.yaml file accordingly and you still receive **404** when you `GET /actuator/health/liveness` there's a slim chance that your application.yaml file is not getting picked up by the Spring Context. You can check if this is the case by changing the port of the application

```
server:
  port: 8081
```

If your application doesn't start on a different port, it is safe to say that none of your configurations have taken place.
I had this issue one or two times with my IDE.

Comment: you can set this in your application.yaml. Access /health/liveness or /health/readiness
management:
  server.port: 8081
  endpoints.web:
    exposure.include: health
    base-path: /
  endpoint:
    health:
      probes:
        enabled: true

Answer (score 5):

If you work with spring 2.3.2 or newer, please add these properties:

```
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
management.health.livenessState.enabled=true
management.health.readinessState.enabled=true
```

Comment: any description?

Comment: This ```management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true``` alone enables the liveness and readiness endpoints. You don't need the individual liveness and readiness configs

Comment: That's right.But depends on the version that you use.

Comment: `management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled` alone works at least since Spring Boot 3.0.2

Comment: [Commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/fe807d6c0ba9793e8447a8de42b7bfed12251be2) that deprecates `management.health.probes.enabled` property